# mongorestore for a collection results in "Killed" output and collection isn't fully restored

Tags: mongodb, digital-ocean, mongorestore

I type the following below:

> > root@:/home/deploy# mongorestore --db=dbname --collection=collectionname pathtobackupfolder/collectionname.bson

Here's the output:

> > 2016-07-16T00:08:03.513-0400 checking for collection data in pathtobackupfolder/collectionname.bson
> >
> > 2016-07-16T00:08:03.525-0400 reading metadata file from pathtobackupfolder/collectionname.bson
> >
> > 2016-07-16T00:08:03.526-0400 restoring collectionname from file pathtobackupfolder/collectionname.bson
> >
> > Killed

What's going on? I can't find anything on Google or Stackoverflow about a mongorestore resulting in "Killed". The backup folder that I'm restoring from is a collection of 12875 documents, and yet everytime I run the mongorestore, it always says "Killed", and always restores a different number that is less than the total number: 4793, 2000, 4000, etc.

The machine that I'm performing this call on is "Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-71-generic x86_64)" from Digital Ocean

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After trying the mongorestore command for the 5th and 6th time after posting this question, this time more explicit output came out that indicated it was a memory issue specific to Digital Ocean. I followed https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-14-04 and the restore finished completely without errors.

Comment: Awesome! Just saved me time ;)

Comment: To clarify: this isn't specific to Digital Ocean. `mongorestore` will be killed if it runs out of memory. Adding a swapfile effectively increases available memory. Digital Ocean happens to have a guide for how to add a swapfile.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to solve it in docker, just increase swap memory in settings.json file